# sbt+spring assembly deduplicate: different file contents found in the following

Tags: scala, spring-boot, sbt

where i use sbt assembly my scala project, i met a error like that: deduplicate: different file contents found in the following: and below is the picture:

[image: SBT compile error]

and my **build.sbt**:

[image: build.sbt]

sbt version: 0.13.15
scala version: 2.8.11
jdk: 1.8

Comment: can you please copy paste your `build.sbt` instead of posting picture to different place. Make SO users easier to help.

Comment: libraryDependencies += "org.springframework" % "spring-beans" % "3.1.0.RELEASE",
    libraryDependencies += "org.springframework" % "spring-context" % "3.1.0.RELEASE",
    libraryDependencies += "org.springframework" % "spring-core" % "3.1.0.RELEASE",
    libraryDependencies += "org.springframework" % "spring-orm" % "3.1.0.RELEASE",

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the assembly merge strategy to either take one of the files, concat them or remove them completely:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("org", "springframework", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case x => MergeStrategy.defaultMergeStrategy(x)
}
```

Comment: but how do i write the build.sbt?

Comment: Copy and paste my answer to your `build.sbt` file.

Comment: still  have the problem`````

Answer (score 0):

I am using jdk 8(tried in 11 also) / sbt 1.4.7 / scala 2.13.3  and the following 2 plugins in my *rootprojectdir/project/plugins.sbt*

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.8.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.15.0")
```

```
 assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {  
      case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.contains("module-info.class") => MergeStrategy.discard
      case x => MergeStrategy.defaultMergeStrategy(x)
    }
```

Also I have added the above strategy in my build.sbt, but still getting the same error. The sbt-assembly plugin ticket is still open in [github](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/issues/391).

Any workaround will be much appreciated